# Using Custom Settings instead of Map

Tags: apex, customsetting

```
public static String getJob(String JobCode){

    if(JobCodeMap !=null && JobCodeMap.containsKey(JobCode))
            return JobCodeMap.get(JobCode);
     else 
            return '';       

}

public static Map<string,String> JobCodeMap = new Map<string,String>(); 

static{
    JobCodeMap('APPV', 'Approved');
    JobCodeMap.put('CNCL' , 'Canceled');
    JobCodeMap.put('NACC' , 'Not Accepted');
    JobCodeMap.put('TFER' , 'Transferred');

}
```

I am currently performing the above check by storing the key and returning map to populate in VF . How can I do the same using Custom Settings ?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for list custom settings? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_customsettings.htm

Answer (score 3):

Create a custom setting with one field (ex: value). 
Create records of that custom setting where name will be your key of map and give the value of map to the field of custom setting.

You can retrieve the values using the following code:

```
public static String getJob(String JobCode){

    if( <Custom_Setting>.getInstance(JobCode) != null )
        return <Custom_Setting>.getInstance(JobCode).value__c;
    else 
        return '';       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create Custom settings and it should have one custom field.
Suppose the name of custom setting is `JobCode__c` and it has two fields in it namely `Name`(standard field, stores the key of the map) and `Value__c`(Custom field, stores the value of the map)

Apex code for accessing the custom settings is:

```
// Store the custom settings data in a map
public static Map<String, JobCode__c> JobCodeMap = JobCode__c.getAll();

public static String getJob(String JobCode){

    if(JobCodeMap !=null && JobCodeMap.containsKey(JobCode))
        return JobCodeMap.get(JobCode).Value__c;
    else 
        return '';       
}
```